# fetching text messages from sip header or msg body

Tags: iphone, pjsip

I am trying to get server text response that sent after i make the dial

am getting the log like this

> From: ;tag=as121b5ca6
>
> To: "me" ;tag=FP0KRz3fkxBtR6q19Er1ykMXhHCqtqOU
>
> Call-ID: ltPywl5Qkt5JwdG47.U0K2J.R.YZN0my
>
> CSeq: 103 MESSAGE
>
> User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 1.6.2.18
>
> Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
>
> Content-Length: 137
>
> ResultHead=STARS1STARSText=STARS 2764 6053 2778 7089 7541 7156 4997 3457 4438 3666 2246 1307 3666 2246 300 4838 7230 4577 4216 3811 STARS

i want to fetch the 'ResultHead'

knowing that i get many like these messages ..is there any function (am sure there is  but i cant see it ) to fetch this messages only or at least the header as string ..

i think i need to use this function but i dunno how!!

```
static pjsip_rx_data *get_rx_data(pjsip_event *e)
{
  if (e->type == PJSIP_EVENT_RX_MSG)
     return e->body.rx_msg.rdata;

  if (e->type == PJSIP_EVENT_TSX_STATE && e->body.tsx_state.type == PJSIP_EVENT_RX_MSG)
  return e->body.tsx_state.src.rdata;

 // There's no rdata on this eevnt
  return NULL;
 }
```

*I use siphon on top of Pjsip ..thnx
i hope my question is clear

Answer (score 2):

looks i ended up answering my question

since its hard to find the answer at least it was for me .. I'll post it in hope that somebody will make use of it ..

first you need to create new module and register it ,

fisrt create the pjsip_module

```
pj_bool_t logging_on_rx_msg(pjsip_rx_data *rdata);

static pj_status_t logging_on_tx_msg(pjsip_tx_data *tdata);

static pjsip_module my_pjsua_msg_logger =
```

{

```
 NULL, NULL,                /* prev, next.      */
{ "my_mod-pjsua-log", 13 },     /* Name.        */
-1,                 /* Id           */
PJSIP_MOD_PRIORITY_TRANSPORT_LAYER-1,/* Priority            */
NULL,               /* load()       */
NULL,               /* start()      */
NULL,               /* stop()       */
NULL,               /* unload()     */
&logging_on_rx_msg,         /* on_rx_request()  */
&logging_on_rx_msg,         /* on_rx_response() */
&logging_on_tx_msg,         /* on_tx_request.   */
&logging_on_tx_msg,         /* on_tx_response() */

NULL,               /* on_tsx_state()   */

};
```

in the sip_connect function use

```
    pjsip_endpt_register_module(pjsua_get_pjsip_endpt(), &my_pjsua_msg_logger);
```

and now the implementation of the reciepient functions

```
static pj_status_t logging_on_tx_msg(pjsip_tx_data *tdata)
{

/* Important note:
 *  tp_info field is only valid after outgoing messages has passed
 *  transport layer. So don't try to access tp_info when the module
 *  has lower priority than transport layer.
 */


/* Always return success, otherwise message will not get sent! */
return PJ_SUCCESS;
}



pj_bool_t logging_on_rx_msg(pjsip_rx_data *rdata)

{

NSLog(@"\n recieving rx msg %s--end my joy",rdata->msg_info.msg_buf);

if (rdata->msg_info.msg->type == PJSIP_RESPONSE_MSG)

{

   do something 

}

return PJ_FALSE;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer, probably saved me quite a bit of time!